# Incorrect Stopping Application After Back Pressing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, backpressure

Logs after back button pressed:

> 11-07 22:48:08.376: D/AndroidRuntime(5325): Shutting down VM
>   11-07 22:48:08.376: W/dalvikvm(5325): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162d700)
>   11-07 22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-07 22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity
>
> {com.some.pack/com.some.packNY}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 11-07 22:48:08.384:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5325):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity
>
> (ActivityThread.java:3627) 11-07 22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
>   11-07 22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:153) 11-07
>   22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
>   11-07 22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-07
>   22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-07 22:48:08.384:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5325):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 11-07
>   22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-07
>   22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 11-07 22:48:08.384:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5325):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>
> (ZygoteInit.java:739) 11-07 22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555) 11-07
>   22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-07 22:48:08.384:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5325): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-07 22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):   at
>   com.some.pack.NY.stop(NY.java:100) 11-07 22:48:08.384:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5325):   at com.some.pack.onDestroy(NY.java:106) 11-07
>   22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):     at
>   android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5302) 11-07
>   22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy
>
> (Instrumentation.java:1117) 11-07 22:48:08.384:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5325):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity
>
> (ActivityThread.java:3614) 11-07 22:48:08.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):
>     ... 11 more 11-07 22:48:08.392: W/ActivityManager(408):   Force
>   finishing activity com.some.pack/.MainActivity 11-07
>   22:48:09.079: W/ActivityManager(408): Activity pause timeout for
>   ActivityRecord{41985990 u0
>
> com.some.pack/.MainActivity} 11-07 22:48:09.095:
>   W/Settings(4780): Setting bugreport_in_power_menu has moved from
>   android.provider.Settings.Secure to
>
> android.provider.Settings.Global. 11-07 22:48:09.095: E/Cryptfs(124):
>   not running with encryption, aborting 11-07 22:48:09.923:
>   I/Process(5325): Sending signal. PID: 5325 SIG: 9 11-07 22:48:09.946:
>   W/InputDispatcher(408): channel '419e2ff0
>   com.some.pack/com.some.pack.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer
>
> closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9 11-07
>   22:48:09.946: E/InputDispatcher(408): channel '419e2ff0
>   com.some.pack/com.some.pack.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is
>
> unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: it would be easyer to look at if you would post the stack trace

Comment: what happen if u comment "stop();" in the OnDestroy() method?

Comment: you should call `stop()` only if `mp` and `mp2` exist and are started.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post the logs, it's a little harder to figure out, but definitely there's a huge gap in your implementation which will end in a NullPointerException, you are initializing "mp" and "mp2" in a click listener, and stoping them in onDestroy, however you are not checking for null values in method "stop", which will definitely cause a NPE, if you go to the activity, and DO NOT Press the button that plays and assign values to the "mp and mp2" references then when pressing back, and onDestroy (which calls stop) is called, CRASH! because mp and mp2 are null...

Hope thos Helps.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple if condition inside your onPrepared() onStop() onDestroy() and onCompletin():

```
  if(mp != null && mp2 != null){
    // Now You wont get runTime problems.
  }
```

Comment: i.e.
`public void onDestroy() {
if(mp != null && mp2 != null){
stop();
  }
}`
right?